# Confusion: Webdesign, Wordpress, Server?!

Tags: php, css, wordpress, ubuntu

I am an absolute beginner concerning Webdesign and do not even know where to start. I found out that Webpages use HTML/CSS, okay so far. I know how to use HTML. Now I found out that the webpages nowadays are often createt with CMS why I wanted to use Wordpress on my Laptop (ubuntu 14.2). But in the Documentation, how to install WP, they talk about servers?!  I tried to follow the turorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04

, installed Apache2 (because they say I need LAMP) but I cant reach "my Servers IP adress" when trying out Apache? 
Please someone bring light into the dark room, I am kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are no where near ready to even think about WordPress if you don't even know where a website is hosted.

You obviously have no idea how to code in HTML or CSS and making a jump into WordPress and PHP would just be way to much to take on board.

I would say go away and learn about HTML & CSS first and get a decent knowledge in it using resources like the ones on this [blog](https://www.upwork.com/blog/2014/03/10-best-web-development-tutorials-beginners/)

Then once your up to spec which wont be next week. you should bringyourself to grips with some JavaScript and Jquery most likely Jquery would be the easiest thing for yourself.

Then in a bit more time look into CMS' and what they offer and how they are built and what purpose they serve.

Then learn some PHP & WordPress together.

Your trying to Sprint at Bolts level before you can even see 3cm ahead of you.

take your time learning to develop and design sites is not something that should be rushed. you should enjoy it and really learn the ins and outs of the codes starting with html and css then moving to the bigger guns like JS and PHP.

Hope this helps and hope you have fun learning!

and please do not be one of those people that learns a weeks worth of stuff and think they have cracked it and can all of a sudden start making sites its just not a good look and you'll be the worse off for it all ways living in the world of mediocre.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer I know now at least where to start. I did not know how wordpress and html/css even fit together, I thought more that the one is an alternative to the other one. So lets start with HTML.

Comment: It all eventually builds together when someone say's they built a site using or in wordpress it all still uses HTML and CSS and will be in a far more complex manner than standard so its best to get there first before moving onto CMS

Answer (score 1):

In general, any website on the internet will be hosted on a server. You also need a domain name (the address of your website).

In your case, you want to install WP on your laptop, the laptop will become a server. By default, your server IP address should be localhost OR 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I think I still do not understand how wordpress works. I thought it is more like Kompozer, Eclipse, ... an IDE or editor. With which I can develop my program and then upload on the Hostserver!? I wont start with this in the next few weeks, since I now know I need to begin with HTML/CSS, but just to put the parts together and finally have an overview.

Comment: OK, Its good to start with the basic first.